# Strange Telerik Jquery Behavior

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik

We inherited a web application project not long ago that made extensive use of the telerik.web.ui controls and needed to add some ajax calls using jquery. The jquery.js file was already present in the project, so I just added the reference to it on the page, added the appropriate calls to do our task:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= tbInput.ClientID %>').blur(function () {
            $.ajax({
                <!-- Additional Code Omitted -->
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This worked fine as long as we were running the web app in localhost, but once we moved it to our QA environment (a Rackspace server), jquery stopped working. No error messages, it just stopped *doing* anything.

To make it function in QA (and consequently production), we had to modify the javascript code to use the telerik controls' embedded version of jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $telerik.$(document).ready(function () {
        $telerik.$('#<%= tbInput.ClientID %>').blur(function () {
            $telerik.$.ajax({
                <!-- Additional Code Omitted -->
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

We would like to be able to use jquery one way or the other in all environments so we do not have to maintain two separate codebases. As near as I can tell, we are using all of the same configuration settings and file versions in all environments, so I cannot figure out why this is happening.

We are using Telerik.Web.UI.dll version 2014.1.403.40 and jquery.js version 1.4.2

Comment: Probably a bad relative URL to the jQuery file so it returns 404? Also, since you have the Telerik controls you do not need another jquery, use the one they bring: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/using-jquery/using-jquery

Comment: As I mentioned, we are using Telerik's embedded JQuery in the QA environment, but that does not work in localhost. Also, no we are not receiving a 404 response, or any other error for that matter. It simply does nothing.

Comment: add your scripts after the script manager and populate window.$ with $telerik.$ as shown here: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/using-jquery/using-jquery#using-the-jquery-brought-by-telerik
With "does nothing" and no errors I have no idea what the actual problem is, sorry.